# Use an Anonymous type on a method that accepts generic

Tags: c#, c#-7.0

I have an OrderMapper class which I use as follows:

```
OrderMapper<Post> m = OrderMapper.For<Post>().Add("title", x => x.Title);
```

Where x is of type Post. The problem is when applying it to anonymous types.

```
var listOfAnonymousObjects = posts.SelectMany(x => x.PostsI18N, (Post, PostI18N) => new { Post, PostI18N });

OrderMapper<??> m = OrderMapper.For<??>().Add("title", x => x.Title);
```

Where x must be of type AnonymousObject in listOfAnonymousObjects. My OrderMapper code is:

```
public class OrderMapper {
  public static OrderMapper<T> For<T>() {
    return new OrderMapper<T>();
  }
}

public class OrderMapper<T> {

  private readonly Dictionary<String, LambdaExpression> _mappings = new Dictionary<String, LambdaExpression>();

  public OrderMapper<T> Add<K>(String source, Expression<Func<T, K>> target) {

    if (!_mappings.ContainsKey(source))
      _mappings.Add(source, target);
    return this;
  }

  public LambdaExpression this[String source] {
    get {
      LambdaExpression target;
      return _mappings.TryGetValue(source, out target) ? target : null;          
    }
  } // this

}
```

How to do this?

Comment: Why not use a concrete class instead of an anonymous one?

Comment: @Alex: Sorry? Did not understand your comment.

Comment: The trick is to use type inference instead of specifying the generic type argument manually. Have a look at how LINQ does it :)

Comment: @juharr: because I am using OrderMapper after SelectMany which returns anonymous ... Just updated my answer to make it more clear

Comment: @MiguelMoura that doesnt mean you **can't** user concrete types, it just means you need to declare one which matches your `SelectMany` projection!

Comment: Then just tack a `Select` on after it to project the results into a concrete class.

Answer (score 8):

You can take advantage of type inference, but that requires you to pass along an instance. This could do:

```
public static OrderMapper<T> ForFromEnumerable<T>(IEnumerable<T> dummy)
{
    return new OrderMapper<T>();
}
```

Usage:

```
var m = OrderMapper.ForFromEnumerable(listOfObjectsOfTypeY).Add("title", x => x.Title);
```

Comment: That's the way. For an even cleaner implementation you could turn `ForFromEnumerable<T>` into an extension method.

Comment: @FedericoDipuma Agreed.

Answer (score 0):

You're much better off using concrete types - just project your anonymous-returning linq queries to a concrete type.

If you *must* support it, you're probably going to have to resort to `dynamic`

```
// no compile-time checking here.
OrderMapper<dynamic> m = OrderMapper.For<dynamic>().Add("title", x => x.Title);
```

Comment: I hate `dynamic`. :)